# Get checked value from radio button group

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, coffeescript

I am populating radio buttons dynamically, and on submit button click I need to get value of the checked radio button from the group.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Numbers">
        <li>        
            <input name="phone-group" type="radio" data-bind="attr: {'id': $data.id}, value: $data.value" >
            <label data-bind="Text: $data.value, attr:{'for': $data.id }" ></label>
        </li>
</ul>
<button role="link">Submit</button>
```

This is the model: (coffeescript)

@Numbers = ko.observableArray([{id:"1",value:"1234"}, {id:"2",value:"5678"}, {id:"3",value:"91011"}])

On submit button click, I need the selected value from the radio button list.

Comment: This doesn't seem related to C# in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using:

```
    function getRBtn(rbName) {
      let opt = document.querySelector(`input[name=${rbName}]:checked`);
      return opt = (opt != null) ? opt.value : 'memo0';  // default value 'memo0'
    }
    // rbName is the radio button name value
    // opt.value is the value associated with the radio button
    // 'memo0' is a default value if no radio buttons have been selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get the checked value in CoffeeScript. However, in JavaScript, using the `name` attribute on the input, you can get the checked value using `document.querySelector()` method:

```
let checkedValue = document.querySelector('input[name="phone-group"]:checked').value;
console.log(checkedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this in a knockoutjs way, the only thing I can see missing is you are not  using the checked binding to get the value selected.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.Numbers = ko.observableArray([{
    id: "1",
    value: "1234"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    value: "5678"
  }, {
    id: "3",
    value: "91011"
  }]);
  
  self.selectedNumber = ko.observable();
  self.submit = function(){
    alert("selected Number: " + self.selectedNumber());
  }
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: Numbers">
  <li>
    <input name="phone-group" type="radio" data-bind="attr: {'id': $data.id}, value: $data.value, checked: $parent.selectedNumber">
    <label data-bind="text: $data.value, attr:{'for': $data.id }"></label>
  </li>
</ul>
<button role="link" data-bind="click: submit">Submit</button>
```